# Xcode 6 Swift Converting String to Int in textfields

Tags: xcode, string, swift, int, xcode6

so i have been stuck with this problem for a very long time now and i cannot figure it out.

so my basic idea is that i have 2 textfields, where the user puts in a number (i don't know how to open the keypad yet would be nice if someone knew how) in both textfields and i want to divide those to numbers by each other.

< Label.text = (Textfield1.text) / (Textfield2.text) >

so i got 3 variables, a label, and two textfields, but i keeps giving me this error that string isn't convertible to a UIint8.

here is a screenshot with the code

[image]

here is the storyboard

[image]
PS: i am kinda new to this Xcode, so the problem might be REALLY obvious :/

here is the error code (it gave me an error when i did it without

let answer2 = textfield1.text.toInt()! / textfield2.text.toInt()!

2014-09-12 15:16:05.764 lb[3107:261572] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ButtonO.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2fb3e5 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110e11967 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2fb029 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010f713383 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2453f0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010fe4716d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010fca9d78 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010fcaa368 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010fcaa5d9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010fcaaa6e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010fbcb2b1 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010fbcb64a -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 276
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010fbd7a81 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010fb825cd -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010fb8529c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010fb84168 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112665513 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f230aac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2267f5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2265b5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2259f6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010fb83bdf -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010fb86990 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  lb                                  0x000000010edb6e5e top_level_code + 78
    24  lb                                  0x000000010edb6e9a main + 42
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001113b3145 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 4):

In order to turn a string into an int, simply use `.toInt()` and it will give you an integer value to use. As for changing the keyboard, you can only bring up a keypad on an iPhone - if you try on an iPad, it will simply show the number side of the keyboard, but the user can change back to normal letters, therefore you need a custom keyboard on an iPad. Nonetheless, below is the code to get the keypad on the iPhone:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: To further clarify, add the .toInt() after .text, so it looks like so: 
`let answer = textField1.text.toInt() / textField2.text.toInt()` 
and store this in an Int value before putting it back in the string like this: 
`label.text = "\(answer)"`

Comment: ok, so it it fixed the errors but i keep getting this error when i launch which i don't understand how to to fix

http://i.imgur.com/GLSix1l.png

Comment: and i don't really know what it means

Comment: I cant tell what problem you have from that unfortunately, copy the console error and add it to your question so i can take a look. Make sure xcode and iOS8 are up to date too. Check developer.apple to make sure

Comment: i fixed it, i had to re write all of the code in a new project and it worked now :)

Comment: How weird, glad its fixed

Comment: I think, having looked at the error, you had hooked a UIButton up to something in the storyboard which no longer existed (such as a removed IBAction) - I got a similar error this morning and it took me ages to figure out

Comment: `toInt` no longer available in Swift 2. Use `Int(string)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
@IBAction var text1:UITextField!
@IBAction var text2:UITextField!
@IBAction var Answer:UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton){
  Answer.text="\(text1.text.toInt()/text2.text.toInt())"
}
```